# Create ORACLE instance Error (Always Free Account)

Tags: instance, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I removed my "VM.Standard.A1.Flex" instance to re-create it, but I get the error:

```
oci_core_instance.generated_oci_core_instance

###########################################################

Error: 500-InternalError

Provider version: 4.66.0, released on 2022-03-02.

Service: Core Instance

Error Message: Out of host capacity.

OPC request ID: 7203c6124c2445990f6b26ef0f43f549/1FB323576CB619AA266C2EFC4BB5D00E/845831335171E98F4ED9C9700EAD993A

Suggestion: The service for this resource encountered an error. Please contact support for help with service: Core Instance

###########################################################
```

But I did not exceed "Always free" parameters for creating instance.
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please contact Oracle's support instead of asking help here.
However, support would say something like "it's out of host capacity, please try again later."